# Get list of all checked nodes and its subnodes in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview list check boxes and the list contains nodes, subnodes and in some cases subnode of subnode. When user check some items i want to get list of selected items.

On this why I get only selcted items of main node:

```
 foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode aNode in tvSastavnica.Nodes)
        {
            if (aNode.Checked == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aNode.Text);
            }
        }
```

How to travers through whole treeview and get checked items in subnodes?

Comment: To understand recursion , first you must understand recursion

Comment: Check my solution and tell me if something is not clear !

Answer (score 19):

If you like LINQ, you can create an extension method that traverses the whole treeview:

```
internal static IEnumerable<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeNodeCollection c)
{
    foreach (var node in c.OfType<TreeNode>())
    {
        yield return node;

        foreach (var child in node.Nodes.Descendants())
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can perform every operations you want using LINQ. In your case, getting a list of selected nodes is easy:

```
var selectedNodes = myTreeView.Nodes.Descendants()
                    .Where(n => n.Checked)
                    .Select(n => n.Text)
                    .ToList();
```

An advantage of this approach is it is generic.

However, because the Descendant() method traverses the whole tree, it might be a bit less efficient than the answer given by @mybirthname because it only cares about nodes that are checked with their parents. I dont known if your use case includes this constraint.

EDIT: Now @mybirthname answer has been edited, it is doing the same. Now you have the loop and the LINQ solution, both are recursive.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

```
public void GetCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach(System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode aNode in nodes)
    {
         //edit
         if(!aNode.Checked)
             continue;

         Console.WriteLine(aNode.Text);

         if(aNode.Nodes.Count != 0)
             GetCheckedNodes(aNode.Nodes);
    }
}
```

You don't make look back into the child notes, using recursion you can do it.

You need method like this ! In your code just call once `GetCheckedNodes(tvSastavnica.Nodes)` and all checked nodes should be displayed !

Comment: Your solution is very efficient, but it is based on the assumption that a checked child node must have its parent checked as well. It will unfortunately not work if a deep sub node is checked and its parent is not. Because this constraint was not asked in the question, I suggest to remove the 'continue' statement and revert the Checked test so the whole tree is traversed.

Comment: @Larry you are correct I will make the the edit ! Thanks for the comment !

Comment: I would love to have seen both methods in your post. I think there are situations where if the parent node is not checked - we do not care about the child nodes. 
Too bad you did not leave the original - I tried checking to see if I could find the edit history - but I cannot ..

Comment: @Ken : just click on the ["edited At"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26542677/revisions) link above and you get the change history

Answer (score 7):

my way:

```
void LookupChecks(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<TreeNode> list)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Checked)
            list.Add(node);

        LookupChecks(node.Nodes, list);
    }
}
```

useage:

```
var list = new List<TreeNode>();
LookupChecks(TreeView.Nodes, list);
```