# PowerShell .NET Collect all checked nodes

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, powershell

I'm almost done with my small GUI to select stuff in a `treeview`. The only hurdle remaining is to collect all the nodes that have a check-mark in front of them. I was trying to do this after clicking the 'ButtonOK', but my `Foreach` isn't really working.

**The code:**

```
$ButtonOK_Click = {
    foreach ($n in $treeView.Nodes) {
        if ($n.checked) {
            Write-Output $n.Name
        }
    }
}

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = '342, 502'
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'

$treeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$treeView.Dock = 'Fill'
$treeView.CheckBoxes = $true

$N1 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 1') 
$N2 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 2')
$N3 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 3')

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Sub 1'
$newNode.Text = 'Sub 1'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$newNode.Text = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null #>

$ButtonOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
$ButtonOK.Location = '245,467'
$ButtonOK.Size = '75,23'
$ButtonOK.Name = 'ButtonOK'
$ButtonOK.Text = 'OK'
$ButtonOK.add_Click($ButtonOK_Click)
$form.Controls.Add($ButtonOK)

$form.Controls.Add($treeView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good example of this in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542568/get-list-of-all-checked-nodes-and-its-subnodes-in-treeview)

Here is a translation in Powershell:

```
function GetCheckedNode
{
    param($nodes)

    foreach ($n in $Nodes) {
        if ($n.nodes.count -gt 0)
        {
            GetCheckedNode $n.nodes
        }
        if ($n.checked) {
            Write-Host $n.Text
        }           
    }   
}
$ButtonOK_Click = {
    GetCheckedNode $treeView.Nodes
}

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = '342, 502'
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'

$treeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$treeView.Dock = 'Fill'
$treeView.CheckBoxes = $true

$N1 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 1') 
$N2 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 2')
$N3 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 3')

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Sub 1'
$newNode.Text = 'Sub 1'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$newNode.Text = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null #>

$ButtonOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
$ButtonOK.Location = '245,467'
$ButtonOK.Size = '75,23'
$ButtonOK.Name = 'ButtonOK'
$ButtonOK.Text = 'OK'
$ButtonOK.add_Click($ButtonOK_Click)
$form.Controls.Add($ButtonOK)

$form.Controls.Add($treeView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Both versions work equally good. It's great to see such a positive community. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I can't access the `Name` property, however the `Text` property does work. You need to call a function from the button click handler which will recurse itself to get all the nodes. Full code below:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function findChecked($node) {
  foreach ($n in $node.nodes) {
    if ($n.checked) { write-host $n.Text }
    findChecked($n)
  }
}

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = '342, 502'
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'

$treeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$treeView.Dock = 'Fill'
$treeView.CheckBoxes = $true

$N1 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 1') 
$N2 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 2')
$N3 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 3')

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Sub 1'
$newNode.Text = 'Sub 1'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$newNode.Text = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null #>

$ButtonOK_Click = {
    findChecked($treeView)
}

$ButtonOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
$ButtonOK.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(245,467)
$ButtonOK.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23) 
$ButtonOK.Name = 'ButtonOK'
$ButtonOK.Text = 'OK'
$ButtonOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ButtonOK.add_Click($ButtonOK_Click)
$form.Controls.Add($ButtonOK)

$form.Controls.Add($treeView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Awesome! In my bigger script where all properties are set, it works with `Name` to. Thank you for your help arco444, really appreciated.