# Create combination of TreeNode and children

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I'm having problem with creating combination of TreeNode and children.

Here is tree :

[image]

And when parent is checked I want to have combination of

```
 "formularzA3 076" 
       and
 "formularzA3 041"
```

I can check if parent is checked :

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes = tree.Nodes;
   foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
   {
      if (n.Checked)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(n.ToString());
      }   
   }
```

But this return on parent.
How can I check if children is checked too?

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.childnodes(v=vs.110).aspx

You can access a `TreeNode`'s children through the `TreeNode.ChildNodes` property (*which is a `TreeNodeCollection`*).

```
   TreeNodeCollection nodes = tree.Nodes;
   foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
   {
      if (n.Checked)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(n.ToString());
      }   
      foreach (TreeNode childNode in n.ChildNodes)
      {
         /* do something */
      }
   }
```

**EDIT**: Why not just get all checked nodes from the *entire* collection as occurred in this answer?: [Get list of all checked nodes and its subnodes in treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542568/get-list-of-all-checked-nodes-and-its-subnodes-in-treeview)

There's also a handy MSDN article on how to iterate through all nodes in a `TreeNodeCollection` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwc698z7(v=vs.110).aspx