# How to find just Checking Nodes Count in TreeView in WinFormApplication in C#?

Tags: c#, treeview

How to find just Checking Nodes Count in TreeView in WinFormApplication in C#? How to do it?

My Code:

```
int itemchecked = TreeView1.Nodes.Count;
if (itemchecked > 1)
{
      messageBox.Show ("Count Checked Nodes is: " + itemchecked);
}
```

But, this code Get Total Count Nodes in TreeView. I want find just checking Nodes Count in TreeView.

Thank's in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of all checked nodes and its subnodes in treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542568/get-list-of-all-checked-nodes-and-its-subnodes-in-treeview)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you may want to consider creating a recursive function to traverse the tree view control and evaluate the appropriate tree node property that denotes whether or not a node is checked.  The function itself could accumulate and return an integer value as the result.